# Parsing xml file with .php extension and php header

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a slight problem. I need to parse a file and populate a web banner with the results. Problem is, the file is called : "_banner_products.php" and it's contents are as follows:

```
<?php header('Content-Type:text/xml'); ?><?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
<carouselle>
 <firstLayer>
   <layerName>Leica Disto X310</layerName>
   <layerProduct>Disto X310</layerProduct>
   <layerPic>http://www.leicaestonia.ee/extensions/boxes_design/flashpics/1334482548.jpg</layerPic>
   <layerPrice>0,-</layerPrice>
   <layerPriceOld></layerPriceOld>
   <layerLink>http://www.leicaestonia.ee/index.php?id=11627</layerLink>
   <layerTimer>01.05.2012 00:00</layerTimer>
 </firstLayer>
 <firstLayer>
   .....
   .....
</firstLayer>
</carouselle>
```

How can I loop through this file to group all the "firstLayer" children into one and so on..
If I just use:

```
$file = fopen("_banner_products.php", "r");
while (!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
}
```

simplexml_load_file throws this-
 "_banner_products.php:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' "

Then I only get the contents of the <...> tags meaning there is no way for me to differentiate if I am out of the  scope already.

Thanks for anyone responding. If anything is unclear I´ll try to explain more.

EDIT.
Thank you for the solution, indeed using the full URL worked:

```
simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/MySite/_banner_products.php");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having issue because `simplexml_load_file` is treating your file like a local xml file .. what you need to do is add the full URL

Example

```
 simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/web/_banner_products.php");
```

Use Case getting `layerName` for example

`_banner_products.php`

```
<?php
header ( 'Content-Type:text/xml' );
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
<carouselle>
 <firstLayer>
   <layerName>Leica Disto X310</layerName>
   <layerProduct>Disto X310</layerProduct>
   <layerPic>http://www.leicaestonia.ee/extensions/boxes_design/flashpics/1334482548.jpg</layerPic>
   <layerPrice>0,-</layerPrice>
   <layerPriceOld></layerPriceOld>
   <layerLink>http://www.leicaestonia.ee/index.php?id=11627</layerLink>
   <layerTimer>01.05.2012 00:00</layerTimer>
 </firstLayer>
 <firstLayer>
   <layerName>Leica Disto X310</layerName>
   <layerProduct>Disto X310</layerProduct>
   <layerPic>http://www.leicaestonia.ee/extensions/boxes_design/flashpics/1334482548.jpg</layerPic>
   <layerPrice>0,-</layerPrice>
   <layerPriceOld></layerPriceOld>
   <layerLink>http://www.leicaestonia.ee/index.php?id=11627</layerLink>
   <layerTimer>01.05.2012 00:00</layerTimer>
 </firstLayer>
</carouselle>
```

**view details**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/lab/stockoverflow/_banner_products.php");

echo "<pre>" ;
foreach($xml as $key => $element)
{
    echo $element->layerName , PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Comment: In addition to this, to loop over the XML you should use code similar to example #4 of http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: If I put the full path
`http://localhost/MySite/_banner_products.php`
It gives me 
`I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/_banner_products.php"`

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to do this is to strip out the first line, and add the XML declaration back in with your code.

You could also parse the file with PHP, using `eval()`, but be **very** sure about what you are parsing, as this could be a very large security hole.